# How to use builtin validation rules in VeeValidate 4?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vee-validate

I'm migrating from Vue 2 to Vue 3, therefore, I want use VeeValidate 4, but the docs say nothing about using builtin rules like min, max, alpha_spaces, etc.

Do I have to create my own validations?

Should I REALY use zod for that?

Is there any predefined rules or it was removed from VeeValidate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules for Vee-Validate are in separated package. See the docs [here](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/guide/global-validators#vee-validaterules).
Then you can simply use the bind `rules` on `Field` of Vee-Validate to add the rules you imported with `defineRule`